# C# create Dictionary of int and arrays

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

How can I create a dictionary containing ints as keys and arrays as Values. Here is what I have tried on dotnetfiddle.net with no luck:

```
Dictionary<int, double[]> dict;
double[] prices = new double[20];
dict = new Dictionary<int, prices>();

Dictionary<int, double[]> dict;
dict = new Dictionary<int, new double[20]>();

Dictionary<int, double[]> dict;
dict = new Dictionary<int, double[20]>();
```

Comment: `Dictionary<int, double[]> dict = new Dictionary<int, double[]>();` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try this.

`Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` is a generic type you can only set contracts type on it.

I think you are looking for `Add` method to add `double` array.

```
Dictionary<int, double[]>  dict = new Dictionary<int, double[]>();
dict.Add(1,new double[20]);
```